# NPE when injection class in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have problem when injection class.

In my configuration I have one class  which setting level of login and then one variable for setting level:

```
  <bean id="config" class="..." init-method="init">   
        <property name="log4jConfig" ref="log4j" />
        <property name="levelLogging" value="9" />
    </bean>
```

and code:

```
public void setlevelLogging(Integer level) {

    if (level == null) {
        set0();
    } else {
        switch (level) {
        case 0:
            set0();
            break;
        case 9:
            set9();
        }
    }
    this.level = level;

}

private void set0() {
    log4jConfig.setLoggerLevel("org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing", "OFF");
    log4jConfig.setLoggerLevel("org.app", "INFO");
    log4jConfig.setLoggerLevel("org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing", "OFF");
}    

public void setLog4jConfig(Log4jConfigJmx log4jConfig) {
    this.log4jConfig = log4jConfig;
}
```

when I want to run this code I got NPE because log4jConfig is null when is `setlevelLogging` calling.

How I can solve this exception ?

now I exclude this class from properties and creating new class in configClass:

```
Log4jConfigJmx log4jConfig = new Log4jConfigJmx()
```

but I dont think this is good idea

EDIT:

I try example below but I have still some problem:

first I got this exception:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

because I am using transactional and AOP so I add default constructor to the class so I have two of them:

```
    public Config() {
    }

    public Config(Log4jConfigJmx log4jConfig, Integer level) {
this.log4jConfig = log4jConfig;
setlevelLoggin(level);
    }
```

setlevelLogging ...

```
 <bean id="config" class="..." init-method="init">   
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="log4j" />
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="9" />
 </bean>
```

but now I have still NPE

pls help

Comment: You can use both as constructor args, so order won't change.

Comment: hm and is possible to combine constructor arg with property ?

Comment: What does your class look like now and what does your spring xml look like?  Also,  did you check with debug that the passed log4j is not null?

Comment: updated and log4j is null because constructor without arguments is using

Answer (score 1):

You should place the code from the method `setLoggingLevel` in the init method.

Only leave `this.level = level` so it is a plain setter.

The init method is called after all the properties have been set.

----EDIT after comment----

After you comment I suggest you use a constructor:

```
public Class(Integer level, Log4jConfigJmx log4jConfig){
   this.log4jConfig = log4jConfig;
   setLevelLogging(level);
}

<bean id="config" class="..." init-method="init"> 
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="9"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" ref="log4j"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I cant because this method is visible from jmx so when I want to change log4j setting dynamicaly I call this method and when I place this method in init I lose this function

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor-args like this:

```
<bean id="config" class="..." init-method="init">   
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="anotherExampleBean"/></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="int"><value>9</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then your constructor can initialise both variables whilst keeping your setter methods in place.

E.g.

```
public MyClass(Log4jConfigJmx log4jConfig, Integer level) {
    this.log4jConfig = log4jConfig;
    this.setLevelLogging(level);
}
```

---

You can also try making the log4jConfig `autowired`.

Change your bean config back to:

```
<bean id="config" class="..." init-method="init">   
    <property name="levelLogging" value="9" />
</bean>
```

And then simply annotate a field in your class to be autowired:

```
@Autowired
private Log4jConfigJmx log4jConfig;
```

Add this at the top of your spring context to enable annotations:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: hm and is possible to combine constructor arg with property ?

Comment: yes it is just add `<property>` elements below the `constructor-args` and they will be set after the object has been constructed

Comment: Updated with another suggestion